# How to subscribe to new messages added to output panel in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is there an api in VS Code to subscribe to new messages displayed in output panel by a specific extension?

Below is the screenshot of what I am talking about. I have gone through [VS Code api](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api) but couldn't find what I am looking for.

[image]

Comment: to whoever voted to close this as a tool recommendation, this is asking whether and what part of the VS Code extension API to use to solve a specific problem. Such questions are on-topic and there are plenty of other on-topic questions like this. This is akin to asking for links to official documentation, [which is also on-topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417732/11107541).

Comment: To future users who are going to vote to close this, please leave a comment as what is wrong so that I can improve. Thanks!